# How to deselect input field when tapping return on mobile keyboard (iOS)

Tags: javascript, ios, ionic-framework, return, keyboard-events

I haven't tested this yet on Android, but on iOS, I know for sure it's not working.

I have an input field where people can write stuff. I want to deselect (remove the focus) the input field when someone taps on "enter" on the **native iOS keyboard**... yet it does not work. It just keeps it's focus on the input field, while I want to get rid of the focus on the input field.

I am using Angular / HTML / Ionic / pure JavaScript. I have a lot of input fields, so am using **classnames**. Is there a way to achieve this?

[image]

You can see the input fields here and the keyboard beneath.

Comment: Why do you want to remove the focus ? Does the keyboard stay open ? Or do you want to focus on another element ? Have you used a `<form>` element in HTML ?

Comment: Hi there. I want to remove the focus, because I have everything blurred when I am focusing on the input field. To get rid of the blur, I need people to enter / tap the keyboard so that they can actually see the search results. And no, I am not using a form element. It's just a plain input field outside a form.

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: Well, yes. Looking here: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/getting-the-keyboard-go-button-to-act-like-the-app-submit-was-clicked/5305/6. I tried it, but it's about a form... and my input field is outside a form. It's not a form at all, so I want a different behaviour. I just want it to deselect the input field when I tap on the default Android or iOS "return" button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just listen to the `keydown` event of the input box and check whether the event's `keyCode` is 13 (key code of enter).
When this happens you can just call the `blur()` method of the input element.

It would look like [this](https://codepen.io/Siphalor/pen/JWdqyj).

Comment: Thanks... yet I am using classnames and it's not working like that... Could you provide an example with that too? I have made this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JWKOao

Comment: You have to handle the return value of getElementsByClassName() as an array. https://codepen.io/Siphalor/pen/bqeaGj?editors=1111

Comment: Wonderful! Can we do this without having to use the "onload" btw?

Comment: We could write the onload commands outside pf any function. Then they're often executed when the browser gets them from the server. So you maybe have to place your `script` tag __under__ the inputs. I have updated the code pen so it doesn't use onload anymore.

Comment: Thanks. I can't get it to work in Ionic, but I accepted your answer anyway. Merci!

Comment: You can also watch for document.activeElement and the event.target in order to test if the target is focused in your handler. target.type === 'text' ? target.focus() : document.activeElement.blur();